# jQuery dynamic var change and dynamic if else checking

Tags: jquery, variables, dynamic, if-statement

I want to create a var which changes it's value on click and then I want to check the value of the var using ***if*** and preform a series of animations. If the value of the var isn't lets say ***projects*** I use else to reverse the animations.

```
var url = "work";

if (url == "home") {
$("#homeBox").fadeIn(200)
}

$("#homeTab").click(function(){
var url = "home"
})
```

I will use this for a one-page website so the var values are basically the urls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you need, this would solve it:

```
var url = "work";

function animate(){
  if (url == "home") {
    $("#homeBox").fadeIn(200);
  }
}
animate();

$("#homeTab").click(function(){
  url = "home";  //I removed 'var', because it would create a local variable.
  animate(); //Perform the animation/deanimation
})
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to place your if check inside the click handler.  Something like this:

```
var url = "work";

$("#homeTab").click(function(){
   var url = "home";

   if (url == "home") {
      $("#homeBox").fadeIn(200);
   }
   else {
      $("#homeBox").fadeOut(200);
   }

});
```

Also, don't forget those semicolons at the end of every line.

Comment: As I look into it I seem to have a problem. Changing the var works fine but when I switch to a new tab the else statement doesn't work. And the else statement is very important in my case because I want to use "else" to fadeOut the previous page.

Comment: Well, all your tabs must have something in common - a parent container, or a CSS class.  You can fade out all tabs and then fade in the appropriate one.